# python list expression

Tags: python, list, expression

Say I got a string:

```
s = '''1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
'''
```

I want to turn each line of string `s` into a list of floating-point value, that is:

```
l = [[1.0 2.0 3.0], [4.0 5.0 6.0], [7.0 8.0 9.0]]
```

How can I do this in one line?

Comment: You ask for a "list of float numbers" (I assume you mean of floating-point values, i.e. the `float` type), but then you describe a list of lists of integers. What **exactly** do you want? If it's supposed to be a list of lists, then what determines where one sublist ends and the next begins?

Comment: Why one line?  Is this homework?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, sorry, edited.

Comment: @S.Lott, it's not, I was trying to do that in line, but failed.

Comment: I'll ask again.  Why one line?  There's no value in that.  Why do it?  No one wins at Code Golf.

Comment: @S.Lott, well, actually I was trying to process a file whose content looks like `s`, when I started coding, I kinda compelled myself to do that in one line, that's it. But sir, I don't quite understand 'No one wins at Code Golf`, what do you mean?

Comment: Code Golf is the game of writing things in the fewest lines of code.  In the long run, it helps no one.  The author wastes time writing it.  Maintainers can't understand it and replace it, wasting yet more time.  Code golf -- one liners -- that aren't obvious and require asking questions on Stack Overflow are merely obscurity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
s = '''1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9'''

l = [ map( float, i.strip().split(" ") ) for i in s.split( "\n" ) ]
```

Note `strip` isn't needed when there isn't 'loose' spaces. 
Strip works as `trim` eg. in php .

Answer (score 8):

```
[[float(v) for v in l.split()] for l in s.strip().split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 2):

This iterates through lines first, and then through strings and converts strings to floats. If you want the converstion to integers, change `float` to `int`.

```
[[float(x) for x in line.split(' ')] for line in s.split('\n')]
```